# Angular Production Build is stuck at 14%

Tags: angular, typescript, production, aot

I am running angular build command for my project

> ng build --prod --aot --vendor-chunk --common-chunk
>   --delete-output-path --buildOptimizer

[image]

Version details:

[image]

package.json

> 

```
{
  "name": "portal",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {//scripts here//
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@agm/js-marker-clusterer": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@angular/animations": "7.2.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.6",
    "@angular/common": "7.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "7.2.11",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.24",
    "@angular/forms": "7.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "7.2.11",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.2.11",
    "@angular/router": "7.2.11",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^4.1.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-charts": "^3.3.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^3.4.4",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^3.0.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^2.1.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^3.7.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^3.2.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^1.5.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^1.3.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "^1.1.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-treeview": "2.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.5.0",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.5.7",
    "@progress/kendo-file-saver": "^1.0.7",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^2.56.0",
    "@swimlane/dragula": "^3.7.3",
    "@swimlane/ngx-dnd": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/arcgis-js-api": "^4.10.0",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^3.1.43",
    "@types/file-saver": "^1.3.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.13",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.30",
    "ang-jsoneditor": "^1.6.2",
    "angular-froala-wysiwyg": "^2.9.4",
    "angular2-cookie": "^1.2.6",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.9.0",
    "angular2-uuid": "^1.1.1",
    "angular2gridster": "^6.0.2",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "compact-timezone-list": "^1.0.6",
    "core-js": "2.5.7",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "esri-loader": "^2.9.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "3.4.1",
    "jsoneditor": "^5.14.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "ngc-float-button": "^1.2.1",
    "ngx-clipboard": "12.0.0",
    "ngx-facebook": "2.4.0",
    "ngx-gallery": "^5.9.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-mask": "7.9.9",
    "ngx-moment": "^3.1.0",
    "ngx-owl-carousel": "2.0.7",
    "ngx-pipes": "^2.4.6",
    "ngx-popover": "0.0.16",
    "ngx-rating": "0.0.9",
    "npm": "^6.10.0",        
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "quill": "^1.3.6",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",        
    "zone.js": "^0.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.7.5",
    "@angular/cli": "7.3.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "7.2.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "7.2.11",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.119",
    "@types/node": "^10.9.4",
    "@types/xlsx": "0.0.36",
    "codelyzer": "~5.0.0",
    "dateformat": "^3.0.3",
    "del": "^4.1.0",
    "git-semver-tags": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-bump": "^3.1.1",
    "gulp-conventional-changelog": "^2.0.3",
    "gulp-flatten": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-hub": "^4.2.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.5.0",
    "gulp-merge-json": "^1.3.1",
    "gulp-shell": "^0.7.0",
    "gulp-tag-version": "^1.3.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "js-marker-clusterer": "^1.0.0",
    "karma": "^3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "protractor": "^5.4.0",
    "rxjs-tslint-rules": "^4.8.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.0.3",
    "tslint": "~5.14.0",
    "typescript": "3.1.1"
  }
}
```

Let me know if any other details are required.

Comment: what happens when you give just ng build?

Comment: ng build and ng build -prod is working fine. But issue is coming with aot

Comment: Add the image where it is getting stuck

Comment: Just go with ng build --prod

Comment: how many file you have on your src folder ?

Comment: Unless you have explicitly modified angular.json, --prod flag automatically enables aot compilation.

Comment: @Yanis-git 20files and 4 folders which contains my main code of project

Comment: @Purab  yes for --prod flag my angular.json has aot set as false, so I am setting aot=true by cmd

Comment: You might have to increase node memory `"build-prod": "node --max-old-space-size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --aot",
`

Comment: @khush were you able to solve that by any chance? trying to build a legacy project with the same cli/node versions as you are, facing the same issues with aot

Comment: @Ben Nope. I didn't find any fix for this

Comment: @khush The issue is with the compiler-cli. see my post -
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75906592/7210967